# Can Dreamweaver open .manifest files?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

**Is there any way to edit .manifest files with Dreamweaver (CS 6)?**

I have a HTML 5 page, with a lot of files connected to it. The manifest sometimes needs to change, or I have to give an update online.

This is not possible with Drwamweaver. When I doubleclick the file, Dreamweaver alerts me that there is no valid editor for this extension. When I doubleclick the file in Explorer, it just opens with Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let Dreamweaver know that you want to open .manifest files in code view.

Go to **Edit** > **Preferences**
and choose category **File Types / Editors**

In the input field "*Open in code view*" you add "**.manifest**" as a file extension.
Click **OK** to save your preferences.

Double clicking a *.manifest file will now result in Dreamweaver opening the file in code view.